# Несколько объектов в сессии

Tags: jsp, сессия, java, java-ee

Здравствуйте. Мне надо запихнуть n-количество по checkbox'у в сессию. Я делал вот так из jsp-страницы:

```
if (request.getParameter("trash") != null) { 
    HttpSession s = request.getSession(true);

    s.setAttribute("id",request.getParameter("id"));
    s.setAttribute("type",request.getParameter("type"));  
    s.setAttribute("style",request.getParameter("style"));
    s.setAttribute("name",request.getParameter("name"));
    response.sendRedirect("trash.jsp");
}
```

Но проблема в том, что в сессию добавляется 1 элемент. И еще тогда вопрос, как можно при таком выводе:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${disk}">
<tr>  
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${row.id}"></td>    
    <td><c:out value="${row.type}"/></td> 
    <td><c:out value="${row.style}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

достать переменные и запихать в сессию?

Comment: Не понимает аннотацию <code>@WebServlet</code>, пишет что параметры name и urlPatterns недопустимы

Comment: Это потому, что я сделал JavaEE6-проект. Выкинуть аннотацию и добавить в web.xml.

Comment: Раз пишет, что нет, то это значит, что вы не добавили в web.xml url-маппинг на сервлет. Для каждого сервлета в web.xml должно быть минимум по две записи.

Comment: Спасибо тебе ОГРОМНОЕ все получилось! Теперь вот удалить из корзины буду делать.

Comment: Теперь к этому новая проблема, как остальное вывести. Еще есть 3 поля, пробовал по аналогии, но это криво.

Comment: Сделайте новый вопрос, поглядим.

Comment: Сделал, что-то никто не глядит. Вопрос в том теперь как мне передать эти id в метод и соответственно потом вывести эти 4 строки в jsp???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое может быть только если остальные параметры - null. Других вариантов нет, если только вы где-то не удаляете их потом оттуда.

По второму вопросу: это ужасная редкостная кривизна. Не делайте такое. Вы можете сделать вставку на Java. Но я бы даже не думал о том, как сделать это. JSP предназначена только для вывода. Никакая логика не должна выполняться на уровне представления.

**UPD**

Если хочется сделать что-то такое и нет сил сделать нормально, то можно засунуть всё в бин

*MyPageBean.java*

```
public class MyPageBean {
    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        setParameterToSession(request, session, "id");
        setParameterToSession(request, session, "other... ");  // etc
    }

    private void setParameterToSession(HttpServlet request, HttpSession session, String parameterName) {
        session.setAttribute(parameterName, request.getParameter(parameterName));
    }
}
```

*my-test-page.jsp*

```
<jsp:useBean class="...MyPageBean" scope="request" id="pb">
    <jsp:setProperty bean="pb" name="request" value="${request}" />
</jsp:useBean>

<html> .... my page content
```

Но, всё равно, фактически, я уверен, что это не только кривизна, но она также является бесполезной. Нет смысла класть в сессию такие странные параметры. Обычно всегда можно обойтись без этого странного подхода.

---

**UPD**

### Задача о корзине с товарами

Поскольку появились новые сведения о задаче, то обновляю ответ. Итак, задача - сделать корзину. Для простоты пусть у нас форма с товарами и я просто руками вписываю в текстовые поля id-шники.

Делаем бин с нашими товарами

*CartBean.java*

```
public class CartBean {

    private List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public synchronized void addItem(int id) {
        ids.add(id);
    }

    public synchronized List<Integer> getIds() {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(ids);
    }

    public static CartBean get(HttpSession session) {
        CartBean cart = (CartBean) session.getAttribute("cart");
        if (cart == null) {
            cart = new CartBean();
            session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        }

        return cart;
    }
}
```

*index.jsp*

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:useBean id="cart" class="cg.CartBean" scope="session" />

<html>
  <head><title>Simple jsp page</title></head>
  <body>

  <form action="/add-cart" method="POST">

      <!-- здесь то, что уже в корзине -->
      <c:forEach items="${cart.ids}" var="id">
          <span>${id}</span> </br />
      </c:forEach>

      <!-- а здесь то, что можно будет добавить -->
      <input type="text" name="id" /> <br />
      <input type="text" name="id" /> <br />
      <input type="text" name="id" /> <br />
      <input type="text" name="id" /> <br />
      <input type="text" name="id" /> <br />

      <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Теперь сервлет, который обрабатывает /add-cart

*AddCartServlet.java*

```
@WebServlet(name = "AddCartServlet", urlPatterns = "/add-cart")
public class AddCartServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        CartBean bean = CartBean.get(session);

        for (String value : request.getParameterValues("id"))
            if (!value.trim().isEmpty())
                bean.addItem(Integer.parseInt(value.trim()));

        response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "GET requests are not supported");
    }
}
```

Итак, смотрим:

До всего (у меня уже в корзине три)

[image]

Ввожу ещё пару

[image]

И жму отправить... сервлет отрабатывает и новая index.jsp появляется

[image]

Задача решена.

Как альтернативный вариант, можно действительно наделать 1000 параметров типа id0, id1, id2, но это будет менее удобно обрабатывать на стороне сервлета, но тоже не фатально. И будет выглядит как-то в таком духе

```
    for (String paramName : Collections.list(request.getParameterNames())) {
        if (paramName.startsWith("id-")) {
            String value = request.getParameter(paramName);
            if (!value.trim().isEmpty())
                bean.addItem(Integer.parseInt(value.trim()));
        }
    }
```

И, конечно не забывайте, что все эти страшные вещи должны передаваться через POST чтобы не пугать пользователя безумием в URL.

Comment: Нет, просто остальные параметры берутся из JSTL forEach. Я знаю что логику нельзя пихать, но нет времени делать по-другому, пока надо только запихать в сессию. По поводу forEach это не кривизна, это просто вывод из БД, как раз чтоб не пихать логику.

Comment: Если данные из БД, а вы хотите из неё  положить в сессию, да ещё делая это во время генерирования документа.. это настоящая кривизна. Такие вещи можно вынести в отдельный бин, если действительно хочется по быстрому сделать.

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать что-то такое, в цикле считываем из реквеста/сессии:

```
while (null != request.getParameter ("id"+ index)) { /* обрабатываем значение */ index++; }
```

(это если вы не передаете количество, можно его тоже добавить параметром)

с другой стороны если у вас массив/список обьектов, то можно прямо его пихнуть в сессию, а потом сделать редирект.

+1 к тому что не надо пихать ничего такого в сесию :)

Comment: вопрос все таки в том, как организовать запись массива в сессию, а затем извлечь его обратно??? получается получить только последнее значение массива.<br> 
HttpSession ss = req.getSession();<br>
String[] disks = req.getParameterValues("id");<br>
for(int i=0; i<disks.length; i++) {<br>    
ss.setAttribute("id", disks[i]);<br>
}

Comment: В следующий раз смотрите внимательнее на примеры, вот что я имел в виду (только с использованием цикла):

    session.setAttribute("id0", "13");
    session.setAttribute("id1", "15");

С другой стороны, можно все значения засунуть в список/массив а его уже засунуть в сесию:  

    session.setAttribute("id-list", new String[] {"1", "2", "3"});

Comment: )))<code>session.setAttribute("id0", "13");
session.setAttribute("id1", "15");</code><br>
Попробую пояснить: есть таблица, которая выводится на JSP и имеет параметры "id", "type", "style", "name". В этой таблице может быть 10000 строк, так что для каждой строки мне отдельный параметр создавать???)))Атрибут ОДИН - значения разные!

Comment: Тогда вообще не понятно ничего. Зачем вам нужно передавать эти строки через сессию или параметры?? Вы действительно уверены, что это необходимо??

Comment: Уверен более чем, так как это корзина товаров)

Comment: Тогда всё ясно. Сейчас обновлю свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо cy6erGn0m !!!

Comment: Я привёл ПОЛНЫЙ код примера. Должно работать. Тем более что пример элементарнейший.